# I want a 'click anywhere except this div' function that doesnt use 'event.stopPropagation();' or '.length'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 html columns, all of them are filled with child elements, and I want to trigger some jquery when the user clicks anywhere EXCEPT for that one column.

```
$('html').click(function(e) {                    
   if(!$(e.target).hasClass('column1') )
   {
      console.log('triggered jquery');                
   }
}); 

<div class="column1"></div>
<div class="column2"></div>
<div class="column3"></div>
```

`event.stopPropagation()` breaks other jquery events so I'd prefer not to use it.

`.hadClass` will detect if column1 is clicked, but that doesn't include column1's children.

Comment: You could check the if the click position is inside the div rectangle.

Comment: You've just about got it. Add an additional conditional check to look "up" from children, something like `if ($('.column1')[0].contains(e.target) || $(e.target).closest('.column1').length) {` Also I'd recommend using ID attributes for something like this.

Comment: You can use [jquery clickoutside plugin](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-outside-events/examples/clickoutside/) for this. You basically select the item you want to capture outside clicks, like `$(".column-2").bind("clickoutside", function(){});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about checking the event target's `parents()`?

```
$('html').click(function(e) {   
   var $target = $(e.target);                 
   if(!$target.hasClass('column1') && $target.parents('.column1').length == 0){
       console.log('not column1!');
   }
});
```

EDIT: According to the docs, this works and is super short:

```
    $('html').click(function(e) {   
       var $target = $(e.target);                 
       if($target.closest('.column1').length == 0){
           console.log('not column1!');
       }
    });
```

`.closest()` begins matching at the current element and travels upwards, so that simplifies the test.

Comment: You could shorten the condition to `if (!$target.filter('.column1').length) {`, as `filter` will include the current element as well as its children.

Comment: I used the second answer you gave so that gets the check. .length worked for me even though i was having trouble with it in the past. Thanks @ajm !

Answer (score 3):

Try this please:

```
 $('html *:not(div.column1)').click(function(e) {                    
      console.log('triggered jquery');                
 });
```

or

```
$('html').click(function(e) {                    
   if(!$(e.target).hasClass('column1') || $(e.target).closest('.column1').length > 0 )
   {
      console.log('triggered jquery');                
   }
});
```

Comment: You want `.closest('.column1')` to have a length of 0; otherwise, `e.target` is contained inside it.

Comment: it means is column1 or its parent is column1

Comment: Right. Your if test says "if the event target does not have the column1 class or if the event target or one of its parents has the column1 class". OP is looking for the opposite: anything contained outside of column1.